# Shimmer layout api 19

Tags: android, shimmer

I'd like to know why is my shimmer layout black when api is 19, when it's more than 19 it displays as white(the color it should be).

---

API 19  --------------------------------------- API >=20

[image: API = 19] [image: API >=20]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that setting the ShimmerLayout's background to any color(in my case white) caused it to go black on api 19. Just removed it and the problem is solved.